# Script to for allow for tasks to be added to checklist on relevant date

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, task

I have a script which will take a list of tasks look at the check frequency(daily, weekly, bi-annually, clock change(Daylight saving)) and populates a log with these check if the check is due to be completed.

Currently it works for the daily and weekly tasks because that is just comparing two dates and adding 1,7 but I need to be able to have a check that is added to the log just before the clock changes occur so that the relevant team can complete the check.

I believe the main issue is that i am just comparing against a difference in dates.

Here is my current code... if this doesn't make sense please ask away!

```
function fillTasksLog(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var Settingss = ss.getSheetByName('Settings')
var teamList = Settingss.getRange("A2:C").getValues();

for(var team in teamList){
  if(teamList[team][0] != ""){
    var WMsheet = ss.getSheetByName(teamList[team][0])
    var WMSheetLog = ss.getSheetByName('Log')
    var taskList = WMsheet.getRange("A4:I").getValues();
    var taskLog = WMSheetLog.getRange("A4:Q").getValues();

    var nextFreeRow = WMSheetLog.getLastRow()+1
    var count = 0;
      for (var task in taskList){
        var latestDate = new Date("2017-01-21T20:23:26+0000"); 
        var existingTaskFound = false;
        for(var loggedTask in taskLog){
           var uniqueLogID = taskLog[loggedTask][13];
           var uniqueTaskListID = taskList[task][8];
           var uniqueLogDate = taskLog[loggedTask][9];
           var checkFrequencyDays = 0;

           switch(taskList[task][0]){// looks for date type (frequency)of item in log and assigns value
           //ADD WEEKDAYS TO SWITCH
                case "Daily" :
                  //Logger.log("INSIDE SWITCH DAILY: ");
                  checkFrequencyDays=1;
                break;
                case "Weekly" :
                  //Logger.log("INSIDE SWITCH WEEKLY: ");
                  checkFrequencyDays=7;
                break;
                case "Monthly" :
                  //Logger.log("INSIDE SWITCH Monthly: ");
                  checkFrequencyDays=30.5;
                break;
                case "Quarterly" :
                  //Logger.log("INSIDE SWITCH QUARTERLY: ");
                  checkFrequencyDays=91.25;
                break;
                case "Bi-annually" :
                  //Logger.log("INSIDE SWITCH BI-ANNUALLY: ");
                  checkFrequencyDays=182.5;
                break;
                case "Annually" :
                  //Logger.log("INSIDE SWITCH ANNUALLY: ");
                  checkFrequencyDays=365;
                break;
                default :
                  //Logger.log("INSIDE SWITCH DEFAULT: ");
                  checkFrequencyDays=1;
                break;
              }
             if(uniqueLogID == uniqueTaskListID){
                existingTaskFound = true;
                //Logger.log("checkFrequencyDays: "+checkFrequencyDays);
                //Logger.log("LATEST"+latestDate);
                //Logger.log(taskLog[loggedTask][16]);

                if(latestDate < taskLog[loggedTask][14]){
                  latestDate = taskLog[loggedTask][14];
                  if(taskLog[loggedTask][10] == ""){
                    WMSheetLog.getRange('K' + (parseInt(loggedTask) + 4)).setValue("No");
                  }
                }
             }
        }
        if(existingTaskFound){
          var dt1 = new Date(); // today's date
          var dt2 = latestDate;

          // get milliseconds
          var t1 = dt1.getTime();
          var t2 = dt2.getTime();

          var diffInDays = Math.floor((t1-t2)/(24*3600*1000));
          // 24*3600*1000 is milliseconds in a day
          //Logger.log("DIFFINDAYS: "+diffInDays);
          if(diffInDays >= checkFrequencyDays){
            addTaskToLog(WMSheetLog, nextFreeRow, count,taskList, task, teamList[team][0], teamList[team][1]);
            count ++;
          }
        }else{
          addTaskToLog(WMSheetLog, nextFreeRow, count,taskList, task, teamList[team][0], teamList[team][1]);
          count ++;
        }

      }
    }
  }
}

function addTaskToLog(WMSheetLog, nextFreeRow, count,taskList, task, teamName, teamType){
  var todaysDate = new Date();
  WMSheetLog.getRange('A' + (nextFreeRow + count)).setValue(taskList[task][0]);
  WMSheetLog.getRange('B' + (nextFreeRow + count)).setValue(taskList[task][1]);
  WMSheetLog.getRange('C' + (nextFreeRow + count)).setValue(taskList[task][2]);
  WMSheetLog.getRange('D' + (nextFreeRow + count)).setValue(taskList[task][3]);
  WMSheetLog.getRange('E' + (nextFreeRow + count)).setValue(taskList[task][4]);
  WMSheetLog.getRange('F' + (nextFreeRow + count)).setValue(taskList[task][5]);
  WMSheetLog.getRange('G' + (nextFreeRow + count)).setValue(taskList[task][6]);
  WMSheetLog.getRange('H' + (nextFreeRow + count)).setValue(taskList[task][7]);
  WMSheetLog.getRange('N' + (nextFreeRow + count)).setValue(taskList[task][8]);
  WMSheetLog.getRange('O' + (nextFreeRow + count)).setValue(todaysDate);
  WMSheetLog.getRange('P' + (nextFreeRow + count)).setValue(teamName);
  WMSheetLog.getRange('Q' + (nextFreeRow + count)).setValue(teamType);
}
```

Updated Question 13th Jan:

An expected outcome would be that if somebody has a task that must be completed before clocks change(maybe even up to two weeks before) The task will be added to the log on the relevant date. for example this year the clocks change on Sunday the 31st March... I would like this task to be added to the log up to two weeks before, so that the team are aware they need to complete a task. At the moment the script is unaware of the clock change dates and just refers to a simple calculation i.e every 6 months equals 182.5 days

This is the same with a bi-annual tasks

Update images 14th Jan:

[Page for team to update their task list(Sheet entitled team name)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAppo.png)

[Settings page with team information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3XaJ.png)

[Main log populated by each teams task list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z04nu.png)

Another function i need is if a check needs to be carried out on a certain day in the period the script can understand this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations you can improve your question by providing examples of the expected outcome

Comment: I have added an expected outcome, Is this more understandable? :)

Comment: 1) Please share your worksheet or provide a sample of the data in sheets="Settings", "Team X" and "Log". 2) You said _but I need to be able to have a check that is added to the log just before the clock changes occur so that the relevant team can complete the check_; please explain. 3) When you say "clocks change", are you referring to daylight savings? 4) Regarding the update on 13 Jan, please explain this and why the logging of these tasks is different than at any other time of the year.

Comment: @Tedinoz I have added some more detail. I hope this helps. I'm really battling with this one.

Comment: There's a fair bit on inefficiency in the code (e.g. 'getValues' and 'setValues' are very costly) but we can easily fix that. Again, please, when you say "clocks change", **are you referring to daylight savings**? What time zone are you? "Europe/London"? I don't understand the importance that you attach to the proximity of tasks to the start (and finish??) of daylight savings. Please please explain for me.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you for your patience, Yes I am referring to daylight savings. I'm in London. The importance of proximity of tasks: If a team has to change a number of settings before the "Clock changes" they will need to have prior awareness of the task, I have chosen two weeks as it gives them enough warning to carry out any changes or at least make them aware.

Comment: @AndrouxReabow Please refer your twitter and email me.